# Creating user profile pages Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a site where every user has a profile that everyone else can see.

i.e.

```
http://localhost:3000/trista
```

Right now i stupidly pull in all the data in the view using current_user.name etc.

Sorry, this is probably really simple but how do I add the user info for "trista" and not me, the current_user?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that you have a `User` model. And the action you are requesting is the `show` on on your `users_controller`.
This way i believe you have something similar to this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name]) # This option
  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])   # Or this option
```

The thing is, you load the `@user` instance variable so you can use it in your views like this:

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

Using `current_user` will get the logged one. Using `@user`, you can populate it anyway you want in your controller. Hope it gives you some enlightment.

Comment: awesome, thanks. I think you meant @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id]), right?

Comment: Yeah. I wasn't sure about your controller code. Just did some guessing.